# How to change the color of this selected text of the gnome terminal?

Tags: shell, terminal, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to change the color of "[shark@Archshark ~]$" to blue in the terminal but It seems that I can't change it, please help.

[image]

Comment: Can you post what you did already, how did you try to change it and where?

Comment: So far, I have changed nothing. I tried to change it through the color in the preferences menu but it didn't work, I thought it was the bold color option so I changed that but it still didn't change it

Comment: see my response below :)

Comment: Thank you! It changed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prompt colour is governed by your shell configuration files. Assuming you use Bash, you can change the propmt colours in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` files in your home directory. I believe, judging by your prompt, you use Arch Linux, so you may find some information on [prompt colours here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bash/Prompt_customization#Colors).

For other common shells, look [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Color_output_in_console#Shells).